How to consume from EventHubs Emulator with Azure EventProcessor?
Context
I have the local Azure EventHub Emulator running.
I set it up with docker as shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/test-locally-with-event-hub-emulator?source=recommendations&tabs=docker-linux-container
I am using an implementation of Azure SDK's PluggableCheckpointStoreEventProcessor (which itself implements EventProcessor) to read from the EventHub. Link for the abstract class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.primitives.pluggablecheckpointstoreeventprocessor-1?view=azure-dotnet
internal class BasicConsumer : PluggableCheckpointStoreEventProcessor<EventProcessorPartition>
{
    public BasicConsumer(
        BlobContainerClient storageClient,
        string connectionString,
        string consumerGroupName,
        string eventHubName,
        int batchSize)
            : base(
                  checkpointStore: new BlobCheckpointStore(storageClient),
                  eventBatchMaximumCount: batchSize,
                  consumerGroup: consumerGroupName,
                  connectionString: connectionString,
                  eventHubName: eventHubName
                  )
    {

    }

    protected override Task OnProcessingErrorAsync(Exception exception, EventProcessorPartition partition, string operationDescription, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Processing error");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    protected override Task OnProcessingEventBatchAsync(IEnumerable<EventData> events, EventProcessorPartition partition, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Processing batch");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializingPartitionAsync(EventProcessorPartition partition, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Initializing partition" + partition.PartitionId);
        await base.OnInitializingPartitionAsync(partition, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

I am using the recommended Azurite connection string, EventHub Emulator connection string, and setting up BasicConsumer like so:
var blobConnection = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;";
var eventHubConnection = "Endpoint=sb://localhost;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=SAS_KEY_VALUE;UseDevelopmentEmulator=true;";
var storageClient = new BlobContainerClient(blobConnection, "localhost-test");
var basicConsumer = new BasicConsumer(storageClient, eventHubConnection, consumerGroupName, eventHubName, batchSize: 16);

Problem
Unfortunately, I do not see any sign of the BasicConsumer class reading from the local EventHub. It should be the same as any other EventHub. I don't see the Azurite based storageClient being created or any traces from the overridden event handlers.
Previously, when using EventProcessor from legacy Azure SDK, I saw that these event handlers were actually logging/tracing when a partition opened, just not anymore since upgrading.
My current test scenario is starting the EventHub Emulator (Docker-based, which also runs Azurite), also running Azurite separately, and
simply instantiating a BasicConsumer(). I also do a wait to see if the BasicConsumer() begins reading after some time, but to no avail.
How can I read from the local EventHub?
Exceptions found when Debugging
{"Service request failed.\r\nStatus: 404 (The specified container does not exist.)
\r\nErrorCode: ContainerNotFound\r\n\r\nHeaders:\r\nServer: Azurite-Blob/3.31.0
\r\nx-ms-error-code: ContainerNotFound\r\nx-ms-request-id: 2a0f9015-01ff-43e5-b616-6b221da347f2\r
\nDate: Wed, 31 Jul 2024 06:42:43 GMT\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nKeep-Alive: REDACTED\r\n"}


{"The messaging entity 'sb://emulatorns1.eventhubs.emulator.net/testeventhub' could not be found. 
To know more visit https://aka.ms/sbResourceMgrExceptions.  (TestEventHub).  For troubleshooting information, 
see https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/eventhubs/exceptions/troubleshoot"}

From the above exceptions I saw when debugging, it looks like:

I cannot access Azurite spun up by the EventHubs Emulator using the standard Azurite connection string
AND
A non-local service bus endpoint seems to be formed by the Azure SDK for the EventHub Emulator. This seems incorrect. I'd expect a localhost endpoint.


Any Event Hub consumer will read from the emulator just fine - from the client's perspective it has no understanding of whether this is Azure or local.   So long as you're using the connection string from the emulator, you should be fine.    Without logs, errors, or other context - there's nothing more that we can do to assist.

Makes sense, the EventHubs emulator doesn't specify a separate storage client connection string, only the connection string to connect to the EventHub Emulator ("Endpoint=sb://localhost;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=SAS_KEY_VALUE;UseDevelopmentEmulator=true;")
Do you know if I use the same connection string as the emulator for the checkpoint storage in Azurite containers?

Azurite is a separate emulator that the Event Hubs emulator just happens to also use so it is included in the packaging.  You'd access that Azurite instance the same way that you would one that you were running, I'd assume.  The Azure docs should be accurate for this scenario: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio%2Cblob-storage#connection-strings

Got it, that's what I've been using - updated the question with which connection strings I am using and how I construct BasicConsumer
Will keep troubleshooting

I am worried that because the EventHub Emulator runs Azurite in Docker, the blob endpoint would actually be different (not necessarily http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;)

Updated my question with logs from the EventHub Emulator - I see some TenantCacheComponent Exceptions, and perf counter creation errors

We're a bit into the details of how the emulator hosts Azurite and whether or not they intend that to be used by callers.   I've asked the folks who own the emulator to take a look and see if they can assist with official guidance here.

Ended up using Azurite separately, which worked for me - put my findings in an answer below. Thanks for your help Jesse. I am unsure what issues having both Azurite and the EventHubsEmulator-Azurite running will cause, but I was able to "start processing" events.

1. Call StartProcessingAsync()
After debugging for a while, I learned a couple things that were unclear.
Simply constructing your implementation of the PluggableCheckpointStoreEventProcessor does not start any event ingestion process.
You must call StartProcessingAsync() on the consumer to actually begin processing events.
2. Use provided Config.json and Namespace name
I used the Config.json file shown in the tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/test-locally-with-event-hub-emulator?source=recommendations&tabs=docker-linux-container)
but simply renamed the file and environment variable. Renaming the config file to a custom name led to errors when running docker compose.
When using a custom file name, I only saw the following start in the CMD window:

However, upon using the Out-Of-Box Config.json, a Network entity was also started - I've had runs where it didn't start as well:

Additionally, you must use the namespace name emulatorns1 - a custom Namespace name is simply overridden by the emulator.
3. Use a separate Azurite Emulator
When using an Azure SDK provided Event Processor, you must use a BlobContainerClient to actually checkpoint offsets when processing Events.
Although the EventHubs Emulator starts up an instance of Azurite, the standard Azurite connection string won't be able to access this resource.
Please start a separate instance of Azurite separately and be sure to use .CreateIfNotExists() on the BlobContainerClient when setting up your test environnment.
